# Work experience in Data Science: Couple hours with A-level student

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, online-learning

Our company has accepted an A-level student (18-year old, just before uni) for some work experience. The student will be with me for a couple of hours. I do data analysis and I'm quite busy at the moment.
Not sure what I can show him in such a short time, and I would rather do it hands-on.

Any suggestion? Some online resources?

Comment: What about introduce in person (or get a business partner - always nice to get more perspectives on a job) a recent business case that could be addressed with some tree based methods, suggest they watch some YouTube video on regression/classification trees, then let them play with some already written R/python/whatever code that they can modify a bit (including some already done visualizations), have a chatty worn them what results you got and how you presented them, arrange a meeting with someone from HR on what they look for in applications for this type of job (or your boss or a colleague)?

Comment: Kaggle has a few tutorials for beginners - maybe walk him through some of that, with some examples of real-world problems?

Comment: Sounds like good ideas, thanks! I might end up doing a jupyter notebook with some of the code we run.. Although in 2 hours, will s/he have the time to install anything? :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're busy at the moment, perhaps you could take a section of a dataset that you've worked with previously (and have the relevant processing stored somewhere) and let them loose on it. Then in a week or two go back and see where they've got with it.. it has the two prong approach of throwing them in at the deep end and seeing what they can do as well as providing a ready-made learning opportunity for you.

Comment: Not sure what his/her skills are to be honest.. I'll let you know if s/he is advanced enough to be left loose on data :)